# Rails 3 after_destroy observer not being called

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

Here is my model...

## app/controllers/registrations_controller.rb

```
  def destroy
    @registration = Registration.find(params[:id])
    @registration.cancelled = true
    @registration.save

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to root_url, notice: 'Registration was successfully canceled.' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
      NsoMailer.after_cancellation_email(@registration).deliver
    end
  end
```

## app/models/registration_observer.rb

```
class RegistrationObserver < ActiveRecord::Observer
#close registration after seats are filled
  def after_create(registration)
    if registration.orientation != nil
      @orientation = registration.orientation
      close_orientation if seats_equal_zero
    end
  end

#opens registration if a registration is removed
  def after_destroy(registration)
    if registration.orientation != nil
      @orientation = registration.orientation
      open_orientation if seats_equal_zero == false
    end
  end
```

...the after_create action is working fine, but after_destroy is not. This is just name based correct? Naming the action in the observer 'after_destroy' links it the the corresponding controller action 'destroy' no?

I also added puts statements in both the controller and observer actions. I am making it to the controller action OK, but not the observer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't link it to controller action destroy. It links it to the model.

In order for `after_destroy` to execute, you should do

```
@registration.destroy
```

You can have an `after_save` callback and have the same effect

```
  def after_save(registration)
    return unless registration.cancelled
    if registration.orientation != nil
      @orientation = registration.orientation
      open_orientation if seats_equal_zero == false
    end
  end
```

You can have a look at the [documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/v3.2.13/classes/ActiveRecord/Observer.html) for more information

Comment: Hmm...so you can see in my code above I don't want to actually destroy it, I'm just setting the cancelled flag to true. Is there some other way I can get the observer to respond to this action. Should I create a new action?

Comment: Since you are updating the object(registration), `after_save` will be triggered and you can use `after_save` to do the same thing you are doing in after_destroy with the cancelled check